# Remove unneccessary information from log file

Tags: xml, logging, twisted

My Python script writes log file using 
`log.startLogging(sys.stdout)` 
and `log.startLogging(DailyLogFile.fromFullPath('sms.log'))`. It does a good job. 
But it is kinda bulky and dull. So **I wan't to parse it to XML with specific tags and without unnecessary information**, *so it is more aesthetic to a human eye*.

Information what has been sent and to whom: *Phone number (29999999)*, *text (text1)*, *user ID (666)* and *event ID (1)*:

```
2018-04-26 11:42:25+0300 [-] ('29999999', 'text1', '666', '1')
2018-04-26 11:42:25+0300 [SMSManagementProtocol,client] TX WAMP: [7,"psevent:send_sms",{"sms_txt":"text1","id_nr":"666","key":"1","phone_nr":"29999999"},null]
2018-04-26 11:42:25+0300 [-] ('29999999', 'text2', '666', '2')
2018-04-26 11:42:25+0300 [SMSManagementProtocol,client] TX WAMP: [7,"psevent:send_sms",{"sms_txt":"text2","id_nr":"666","key":"2","phone_nr":"29999999"},null]
2018-04-26 11:42:25+0300 [-] ('29999999', 'text3', '666', '3')
2018-04-26 11:42:25+0300 [SMSManagementProtocol,client] TX WAMP: [7,"psevent:send_sms",{"sms_txt":"text3","id_nr":"666","key":"3","phone_nr":"29999999"},null]
```

EVENT (response with status if it is delivered or an error has occured):

```
2018-04-26 11:43:23+0300 [-] EVENT: http://test.com/publicsubscribeon_sms_delivered_OK KEY: 1
2018-04-26 11:43:23+0300 [SMSManagementProtocol,client] RX WAMP: [8, "http://test.com/publicsubscribeon_sms_delivered_OK", "3"]
2018-04-26 11:43:23+0300 [-] EVENT: http://test.com/publicsubscribeon_sms_delivered_OK KEY: 3
2018-04-26 11:43:23+0300 [SMSManagementProtocol,client] RX WAMP: [8, "http://test.com/publicsubscribeon_sms_delivered_OK", "2"]
2018-04-26 11:43:23+0300 [-] EVENT: http://test.com/publicsubscribeon_sms_delivered_OK KEY: 2
```

Is there a way to remove unnecessary log information? All I need is data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is "unnecessary"?  What is "data"?

Comment: unneccessary, for example: '[SMSManagementProtocol,client] TX WAMP: [7,"psevent:send_sms",' and: '[8, "http://test.com/publicsubscribeon_sms_delivered_OK",' All I need is "KEY: 1"/ "key 2" etc. Because it is information - which exactly events were successful. And that is all information I need. (more information = more storage space and it is not good).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by writing custom log formatter.

You will get more details [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)

Check below code which I am using in my applications for logging.

```
log_path = "logs"
log_file = "log"
rootlogger = logging.getLogger('')
fmt = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s-%(name)s-%(levelname)s : %(message)s')
sh = logging.StreamHandler()
sh.setFormatter(fmt)
rootlogger.addHandler(sh)
logsize = 102400
logbackupcount = 100
rfh = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(log_path+"/"+log_file, maxBytes=logsize, backupCount=logbackupcount)
rfh.setFormatter(fmt)
rootlogger.addHandler(rfh)
```

follow below code snippet to write logs.

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(<logger_name>) 
log.info("information")
log.error("Error message")
```